# arrayFilters in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following schema.

```
{
   posts: [
          {
             _id: '5ayuunbdsyuuuyut778'
             replies: [{
                 _id: "67hfudj7e9whduu888",
                 text: "something"
             }]
          }
      ]
}
```

I want to update the text in particular reply.
I am using mongoose.

I have written the query as follows

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
   {'posts.replies._id': _id}, 
   {$set: {'posts.$[post].replies.$[reply].text': "something1"}},
   { arrayFilters: [{'post._id': postId}, { 'reply._id': _id }]}
 )
```

This query is not updating the document.

Am I missing something? Do I need to cast ids using ObjectId

Comment: Are you getting any error? Because above query works for me... Probably your `postId` or `_id` would not be correct... I have tried this `User.findOneAndUpdate(
   {'posts.replies._id': "67hfudj7e9whduu888"}, 
   {$set: {'posts.$[post].replies.$[reply].text': "something12"}},
   { arrayFilters: [{'post._id': "5ayuunbdsyuuuyut778"}, { 'reply._id': "67hfudj7e9whduu888" }]}
 )`

Comment: which version on mongo are you using?

Comment: @Anthony Winslet. I am not getting any error. I am getting the doc without updating when I use {new:true}

Comment: are they updating in the database? And how you are using `multi: true`?

Comment: I haven't used multi: true. Do I need to?

Comment: Sorry I mean `new: true`... How you used it? and put `@` so  that I can get the notification

Comment: @Anthony Winslet User.findOneAndUpdate( {'posts.replies._id': "67hfudj7e9whduu888"}, {$set: {'posts.$[post].replies.$[reply].text': "something12"}}, { arrayFilters: [{'post._id': "5ayuunbdsyuuuyut778"}, { 'reply._id': "67hfudj7e9whduu888" }]}, {new:true} )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `new: true` to get the updated value and cast id to mongoose objectId to make it work

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
   { 'posts.replies._id': _id }, 
   { $set: { 'posts.$[post].replies.$[reply].text': "something1" } },
   { arrayFilters: [{ 'post._id': postId }, { 'reply._id': _id }], new: true }
)
```

Comment: It's not updating in database itself.

Comment: What I have observed is, its updating in mongo shell(3.6). but not through mongoose(5.2).

Comment: Type this command in your mongo shell `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )` and then try again

Comment: Now I am sure your id might not be correct... Put the id hard coded and try

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. I forgot to cast the Object Id in mongoose.

Comment: is it possible to keep the original _id

Answer (score 4):

As arrayFilters are something related to mongodb, you need to cast id in mongoose with ObjectId

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
   { 'posts.replies._id': _id }, 
   { $set: { 'posts.$[post].replies.$[reply].text': "something1" } },
   { arrayFilters: [{ 'post._id': postId }, { 'reply._id': _id }]}
)
```

must be  changed to

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
   { 'posts.replies._id': _id }, 
   { $set: { 'posts.$[post].replies.$[reply].text': "something1" } },
   { arrayFilters: [{ 'post._id': ObjectId(postId) }, { 'reply._id': ObjectId(_id)}]}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

arrayFilters does not accept stringified Object Ids, as opposed to typical filters in mongoose (which cast object ids automatically for you), you must cast object id manually when passing it as filter to arrayFilters).

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
   { 'posts.replies._id': _id }, 
   { $set: { 'posts.$[post].replies.$[reply].text': "something1" } },
   { arrayFilters: [{ 'post._id':new ObjectId(postId) }, { 'reply._id': new ObjectId(_id) }], new: true }
```

this will work, check comments [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-36-array-filters.html#comment-3929752586) for more details