# Update all objects in array and inner array that match

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I have this document structure

```
{
    "_id": <OBJECT_ID>,
    "orders": [
         {
              "userId": 1,
              "handleName": "John Doe",
              "orderAmount": 3,
              "others": [
                   {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "handleName": "John Doe"
                   },
                   {
                        "userId": 2,
                        "handleName": "Maria Gigante"
                   }
              ]
         },
         {
              "userId": 2,
              "handleName": "Maria Gigante",
              "orderAmount": 2,
              "others": [
                   {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "handleName": "John Doe"
                   },
                   {
                        "userId": 2,
                        "handleName": "Maria Gigante"
                   }
              ]
         },
         {
              "userId": 1,
              "handleName": "John Doe",
              "orderAmount": 4,
              "others": [
                   {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "handleName": "John Doe"
                   },
                   {
                        "userId": 2,
                        "handleName": "Maria Gigante"
                   }
              ]
         },
         {
              "userId": 3,
              "handleName": "John Doe",
              "orderAmount": 4,
              "others": [
                   {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "handleName": "John Doe"
                   },
                   {
                        "userId": 2,
                        "handleName": "Maria Gigante"
                   }
              ]
         }
    ]
}
```

I would like to update all the objects that has the `userId` of `1` and `handleName` of `John Doe`.
Note that objects can have the same handle names but different user id. That is why I need to match it with the `userId` first.

For example I want to change the handle name to `Donald Stark`

I would like to have this result:

```
{
    "_id": <OBJECT_ID>,
    "orders": [
         {
              "userId": 1,
              "handleName": "Donald Stark",
              "orderAmount": 3,
              "others": [
                   {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "handleName": "Donald Stark"
                   },
                   {
                        "userId": 2,
                        "handleName": "Maria Gigante"
                   }
              ]
         },
         {
              "userId": 2,
              "handleName": "Maria Gigante",
              "orderAmount": 2,
              "others": [
                   {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "handleName": "Donald Stark"
                   },
                   {
                        "userId": 2,
                        "handleName": "Maria Gigante"
                   }
              ]
         },
         {
              "userId": 1,
              "handleName": "Donald Stark",
              "orderAmount": 4,
              "others": [
                   {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "handleName": "Donald Stark"
                   },
                   {
                        "userId": 2,
                        "handleName": "Maria Gigante"
                   }
              ]
         },
         {
              "userId": 3,
              "handleName": "John Doe",
              "orderAmount": 4,
              "others": [
                   {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "handleName": "Donald Stark"
                   },
                   {
                        "userId": 2,
                        "handleName": "Maria Gigante"
                   }
              ]
         }
    ]
}
```

How is this achieved?

Update:
I forgot that I also have another inner array that I also want to be updated.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [arrayFilters in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324876/arrayfilters-in-mongodb)

Comment: @whoami sorry I forgot that I also have an inner array I want to be updated. I have updated my question please take a look at it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use [$[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) operator to update specific objects in the array

so your update query should look something like

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { _id: <OBJECT_ID> }, // filter part, add the real objectId here
    { $set: { 'orders.$[order].handleName': 'Donald Stark' } }, // update part
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'order.userId': 1, 'order.handleName': 'John Doe' }] 
})
```

$[order] to update only the objects that match the conditions in the array filters

---

### Update

If you have an inner array, and you need to do the same thing for the elements inside that inner array, we could use something like that

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { _id: <OBJECT_ID> }, // filter part, add the real objectId here
    { $set: { 
        'orders.$[order].handleName': 'Donald Stark', // to set the handleName in the elements of the outer array
        'orders.$[].others.$[other].handleName': 'Donald Stark' // to set the handleName in the elements of the inner array
    } },
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'order.userId': 1, 'order.handleName': 'John Doe' }, { 'other.userId': 1, 'other.handleName': 'John Doe' }] }
)
```

we used `$[]` to loop over all the elements in the orders array, then use `$[other]` to update specific elements in the inner array according to the new condition in the array filters

hope it helps

Comment: Indeed this would be the right answer but I have updated my question. I also have an inner array containing similar data that I also want to be updated.

Comment: okay I've updated my answer to handle this, could you check it?

Answer (score 2):

Would something like that solve your problem ?

```
d = {
    "_id": <OBJECT_ID>,
    "orders": [
         {
              "userId": 1,
              "handleName": "John Doe",
              "orderAmount": 3
         },
         {
              "userId": 2,
              "handleName": "Maria Gigante",
              "orderAmount": 2
         },
         {
              "userId": 1,
              "handleName": "John Doe",
              "orderAmount": 4
         },
         {
              "userId": 3,
              "handleName": "John Doe",
              "orderAmount": 4
         }
    ]
}

def change_name(usr_id, old_name, new_name):
    for usr in d['orders']:
        if usr['userId'] == usr_id and usr['handleName'] == old_name:
            usr['handleName'] = new_name

change_name(1, 'John Doe', 'Donald Stark')
```

Comment: Sorry but that data is in a document db collection