# How to do two different arrayFilters in the same mongodb update?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In the application im building I have two updates that I want to do in the same query. I want to find the subdocument with the matching task_id and update its priority. In the same call I want to increment all the subdocuments with a priority higher than 3. Is it possible to combine these two in the same query?

```
    const project = await Project.updateOne(

        // first search
        { _id: req.params.project_id },
        { $set: {'tasks.$[element].priority': req.body.priority, 'tasks.$[element].state': req.body.state }},
        { arrayFilters: [{ 'element._id': req.params.task_id }] }


        // second search
        { _id: req.params.project_id },
        { $inc: {'tasks.$[element].priority': 1 }},
        { arrayFilters: [{ 'element.priority': { $gt: 3 } }] }
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [arrayFilters in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324876/arrayfilters-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must be used different identifiers for your `arrayFilters`. your identifier is `element`. your code must be like that:

```js
const project = await Project.updateOne(
    // first search
    {_id: req.params.project_id},
    {
        $set: {'tasks.$[elementA].priority': req.body.priority, 'tasks.$[elementA].state': req.body.state},
        $inc: {'tasks.$[elementB].priority': 1}
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {'elementA._id': req.params.task_id},
            {'elementB.priority': {$gt: 3}}
        ]
    },
)
```

> NOTE: The identifier must begin with a lowercase letter and contain only alphanumeric characters (from MongoDB official website, [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]))

Comment: What if I wanted to add another array filter? Lets say in the $inc I add another one: '$tasks.$[elementC].priority': 2. And then in the arrayFilter I add another one with this elementC: 'elementC.priority: {$gt: 2}}. I get a conflict error :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simultaneously by using two `arrayFilters`. Consider the below:

**Current collection:**

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "array1" : [
        {
            "k1" : 1,
            "v1" : 100
        },
        {
            "k1" : 2,
            "v1" : 15
        },
        {
            "k1" : 1,
            "v1" : 100
        }
    ],
    "array2" : [
        {
            "k2" : 1,
            "v2" : 10
        },
        {
            "k2" : 2,
            "v2" : 1000
        },
        {
            "k2" : 1,
            "v2" : 20
        }
    ]
}
```

**Query:**

```js
db.collection.update(
    { _id: 1 },
    { $set:
        {
            'array1.$[elem1].v1': 100,
            'array2.$[elem2].v2': 1000
        }
    },
    { arrayFilters: 
        [
            {'elem1.k1':1},
            {'elem2.k2': 2}
        ],
    multi: true
    }
)
```

As you can see that, I have created two filtered positional operator (`elem1` and `elem2`), with the help of `arrayFilters` option. I can used this to perform my updates.

**Result:**

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "array1" : [
        {
            "k1" : 1,
            "v1" : 100
        },
        {
            "k1" : 2,
            "v1" : 15
        },
        {
            "k1" : 1,
            "v1" : 100
        }
    ],
    "array2" : [
        {
            "k2" : 1,
            "v2" : 10
        },
        {
            "k2" : 2,
            "v2" : 1000
        },
        {
            "k2" : 1,
            "v2" : 20
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see in the above updated collection that the `k1` field in `array1` with value `1`, it's `v1` field have been updated to 100 and the `k2` field in `array2` with value `2`, it's `v2` field have been updated to 100.

So in your case you need to do something like below:

```js
updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.project_id},
    {
        $set: {
            'tasks.$[elem1].priority': req.body.priority,
            'tasks.$[elem1].state': req.body.state
        },
        $inc: {
            'tasks.$[elem2].priority': 1
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            { 'elem1._id': req.params.task_id },
            { 'elem2.priority':
                { $gt: 3 }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very useful. What if I want to add another $inc and another arrayFilter to it? Lets say I add 'tasks.$.[elem3].priority: 2' and add this to the array filter same as with elem2. I get an update conflict. How would I go about this?

Comment: I did not understand your doubt, I think it will be good if you ask a separate questions and let me know.

Comment: Thank you I created a new question