# Update multiple array elements with $inc

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document

```
{store : {
        id        : 'STORE1',
        name      : 'Electronics Store',
        locations : [
            {
                id       : 'LOC1',
                quantity : 4
            },
            {
                id       : 'LOC2',
                quantity : 10
            },
            {
                id       : 'LOC3',
                quantity : 5
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to update the `quantity` of multiple elements of the `locations` array based on their `id` field using `$inc`.

For example I want to update `id : 'LOC1'` with +5 to the `quantity` field and `id : LOC3` with +2 to its `quantity` field.

Is it possible to do this with one query in mongodb instead of using multiple queries for each location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [arrayFilters in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324876/arrayfilters-in-mongodb) --> Making it as direct duplicate, Only change is `$set` to `$inc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) `$[<identifier>]`. Below code will be helpful:

```js
db.collection.update(
     {},
     {$inc: {'store.locations.$[elem1].quantity': 5, 'store.locations.$[elem2].quantity': 2}},
     {arrayFilters: [{'elem1.id': 'LOC1'}, {'elem2.id': 'LOC3'}]}
)
```